# Django 1.1 -> 1.2 migration issue

Tags: django

I was just trying to migrate my production server from Django 1.1.2 to Django 1.2.5. When trying to save a model using the contenttypes I get the following error: `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'` I assume this has to do with the migration but I can't figure out how to resolve this issue.

The django model:

```
class RuleInput(models.Model):
    rule = models.ForeignKey(Rule, related_name='inputs')
    type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False)
    # A prio of 0 means a trigger, a prio of 1 means no trigger
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=100, default=0)
```

The saving function:

```
models = ContentType.objects.filter(app_label="rules")

for model, args in inoutputs:
    args['rule'] = rule
    cls = models.get(model=model).model_class()
    cls.objects.create(**args)
```

Comment: please paste the codesnippet for the same ... that should help

Comment: looks like your `save` function is missing `using` in the list of parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a custom Model.save() method that does not take **kwargs. Have a look at [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save).

Answer (score 0):

After the migration, did you change your `DATABASES` variable in your `settings.py`.  Previously, in Django 1.1, database settings were defined as:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'postgresql_psycopg2'
DATABASE_NAME = 'dev'
DATABASE_USER = 'admin'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'secretpassword'
DATABASE_HOST = ''
DATABASE_PORT = ''
```

In Django 1.2, with the introduction of multiple db, database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dev', 
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'secretpassword',  
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

I have a feeling the internal code might be defaulting to `using('default')`.